# SQL: Combining 2 rows to one from 1 table results in more than one row for subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

## What I have:

One table of <strike>fruit</strike> **food (from which I'm selecting fruit)** with two rows for each each fruit, one for small size, one for large size.

```
id | category | subcategory | title  | description       | value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Fruit    | Small       | Plum   | Om, nom, nom!     | 0.50
2  | Fruit    | Large       | Plum   | Om, nom, nom!     | 1.50
3  | Fruit    | Small       | Orange | Mmm, citrus.      | 0.30
4  | Fruit    | Large       | Orange | Mmm, citrus.      | 0.75
5  | Fruit    | Small       | Melon  | Get in mah belly! | 2.00
6  | Fruit    | Large       | Melon  | Get in mah belly! | 3.10
```

## What I need:

I need to combine the two rows for each fruit into one row:

***category**, **title** and **description** will always be the same for each pair of rows.*

***id**, **subcategory** and **value** will always be different for each pair of rows.*

```
id.r1 | id.r2 | category.r1 |  title.r1  | description.r1       | subcategory.r1 | value.r1 | subcategory.r2 | value.r2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | 2     | Fruit       |  Plum      | Om, nom, nom!        | Small          | 0.50     | Large          | 1.50
3     | 4     | Fruit       |  Orange    | Mmm, citrus.         | Small          | 0.30     | Large          | 0.75
5     | 6     | Fruit       |  Melon     | Get in mah belly!    | Small          | 2.00     | Large          | 3.10
```

## What I've tried:

```
SELECT r1.id,
(SELECT r2.id FROM `my_table` r2 WHERE r1.title = r2.title),  
r1.category, 
r1.subcategory,
(SELECT r2.category FROM `my_table` r2 WHERE r1.title = r2.title) 
r1.title, 
r1.description, 
r1.value, 
(SELECT r2.value FROM `my_table` r2 WHERE r1.title = r2.title)

FROM `my_table` r1

WHERE category = "Fruit"
```

...which produces:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

## My question:

How should I modify the above query to achieve what I've described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can readily do this with an aggregation:

```
select category, title, description,
       MAX(case when subcategory = 'Small' then id end) as Small_Id,
       MAX(case when subcategory = 'Small' then value end) as Small_Value,
       MAX(case when subcategory = 'Large' then id end) as Large_Id,
       MAX(case when subcategory = 'Large' then value end) as Large_Value
from my_table f
group by category, title, description
```

Note:  This does not include `subcategory` in the final result because there is no subcategory for the row.

You can also do this as a join, which seems to be the path you were taking:

```
select fsmall.id, flarge.id, fsmall.category, flarge.category, . . .
from my_table fsmall join
     my_table flarge
     on fsmall.subcategory = 'small' and flarge.subcategory = 'large' and
        fsmall.category = flarge.category and
        fsmall.title = flarge.title and
        fsmall.description = flarge.description
```

Depending on whether you might have some missing rows, you might want a `left outer join` or `full outer join`.

Comment: Thank you for the choice of solutions and each explanation. Solution 1: This works perfectly. I see what you mean about subcategory. The subcategory value is instead expressed in the column titles for the ids and values. Solution 2: I cannot intuit this correctly to confirm whether or not it works and whether or not the produced rows are the same. Should "fruit" (the category value) not be "my_table" (the name of the table) or am I way off the mark? Also, is the ellipsis (. . . ) functional or am I to assume that other columns are to be added? Much thanks for your help.

Comment: @DominorNovus . . . I called the table `fruit`, but I just replaced it with `my_table` as in your question.  Does this resolve your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I modified the column selection of the second solution and added a WHERE condition at the end of the query. The end result produced the exact same amount of records as the second solution. The modified code: http://pastebin.com/1BDfWbC9

Comment: Is there a possibility to use the second option, but let the first joined table without name? Because I need to edit existing query and I can't add prefix like "fsmall." before every column... => something like "..from my_table join my_table flarge.."

Comment: @LukasSalich . . . I don't really understand the question.  It is better to ask a new question as a question rather than in a comment.

Comment: I know, but I don't have that much time for it. It's complicated, thanks.